# Octave coding - How many vectors rotated by an angle is within the distance of another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, matlab, octave

I don't know if this is the right forum but

I am trying to code a rotating vector `v` by an angle `theta` anticlockwise `n` times around a circle. Afterwards, set a variable `r` to be the number of these `n+1` vectors that are within (strictly less than) distance `d` of vector `w`.

So far what I've done is times `(n+1)` by the rotational vector `[cos(theta),-sin(theta);sin(theta),cos(theta)]` with vector `v`.

So

`a=(n+1)*[cos(theta),-sin(theta);sin(theta),cos(theta)]*v;`

I know I have to somehow incorporate `norm(a-w) <= w` or something as that gives the distance between the two vectors but I'm kind of stuck on how to do so.

Alternatively, I am also thinking that instead of times'ing by (n+1), I'm thinking that maybe it's wrong and that I have to make a loop like for n=1,2,...,k, if this vector is within norm(a - w) < d then sum, else disregard or something.

This would be easy if it was manual as it would only require multiplying the rotational vector by v and find the distance between the new rotated vector and vector w, and repeat it again for however many n's but I  am having trouble coding this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do a for loop, as you suggest. Something similar to the following:

```
A = [cos(theta), -sin(theta); sin(theta), cos(theta)];

r = 0;
for k=1:n
    v = A*v;
    if norm(v-w) < d
        r = r + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Right! This looks perfect. How would I include the first case before rotating as well ? to include the vector before any rotation ?

Comment: I think maybe just move the "$v = Av$" line to after the "if" statement, and then change the "for" loop to start at 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I have tried both
```r = 0;
for k=0:n
 v = A*v;
 if norm(v-w) < d

        r = r + 1;
    end
end```
as well as
```r = 0;
for k=0:n
 if norm(v-w) < d
 v = A*v;
        r = r + 1;
    end
end```

First answer I get is 6, and the next answer I get is 0. The correct answer is 5, which is what I get from your original coding. But if I try it with another input, the value is missing the original vector counted.

Comment: you could just add another "if" statement before the for loop to check if the original vector is close enough.

Comment: Thank you ! I ended up trying ```A = [cos(theta), -sin(theta); sin(theta), cos(theta)];

r = 0;
v=v;
 if norm(v-w) < d;
  r=r+1;
end
 for k=1:n
   v = A*v;
    if norm(v-w) < d
           r = r + 1;

    end
end```